# Cannot create a presigned Url when I give the following IAM role access: arn:aws:s3:::mybucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting a very wierd issue regarding to creating presigned url. The code in a beasntalk creates presigned url which is good and there is no problem with the code. However when I give the following access to the instance profile of the beanstalk  I am not able to hit the see the image though a long url is generated.:

```
  {
        "Action": [
            "s3:*",
            "s3:List*",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:Delete*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

and mybucket is the bucket that I have my images there and I create my presigned url from there.
Interestingly when I try this:

```
  {
        "Action": [
            "s3:*",
            "s3:List*",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:Delete*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

it starts working. But I do not want to give * access and this does not make sense at all.
I am just using mybucket why does it work when I give access * and not when I give access to just mybucket. Any idea?
Am I missing anything?

***Update***

More specifically if I want to be able to view my presigned url(A valid link) I need to have the following part in my IAM policy:

```
{
        "Action": [
            "s3:Get*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add GetObject permissions to your IAM role then your presigned URL is not created correctly. You do not need GetObject permission in your policy for a presigned URL for an HTTP GET.

Note: The following is bad policy. You are granting all permissions in the first line and then specifying additional permissions in the next three lines which does nothing additional.

```
    "s3:*",
    "s3:List*",
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:Delete*"
```

Comment: right I was testing the stuff and forgot to fix it . I just did not get your solution so should I remove GetObject? if I do remove GetObject on arn:aws:s3:::* then it will stop working

Comment: A presigned URL does not use your policy. Think of it this way, your presigned URL is designed for the Internet which would know nothing about your IAM role. Go back a revisit the presigned URL that you are generating.  This is where your problem is.

Comment: So the beasntalk which my code in running on needs access to be able to get the image from the bucket and creates presigned url and when I "arn:aws:s3:::*" to the beanstalk(not public) then it creates the presigned url properly.

Comment: So the issue is the beanstalk access level to s3: this works : "arn:aws:s3:::*" with GetObject and strangely not working when I do not have it

Comment: Just for more clarification "arn:aws:s3:::*" does not give access to public and just the beasnatlk where my code is running on it

Comment: Your beanstalk IAM role does not need GetObject access to generate a presigned URL. It needs GetObject access to READ the object.

Comment: Yeah exactly there I have a problem I give enough access and I read my objects only from that buckets but when  remove this  "arn:aws:s3:::*" I see presigned url generated and when i hit the link I cannot view the image: I get access denied

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve: 1) Read an S3 object using a presigned URL OR 2) Read an S3 object from an EC2 instance using an IAM role from your code such as PHP, etc? Your question is mixing together two very different things.

Comment: So I read the object and create the prsigned url as follows: $presignedUrlThumbnail = $s3Connection->getPresignedUrl('Photo/' . $smallImageFileName, AWS_SEARCH_BUCKET, PRESIGNED_KEY_TIMEOUT_MINUTES); but if I do not add  "arn:aws:s3:::*" the generated link is not working

Comment: If I add that evrything is fine